# I just saw an ad for the Stack Overflow 2012 User Survey, but when clicked the survey reports it's closed

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-developer-survey

I assume this means the Stack Overflow ad cache needs cleaned out somewhere.

[image: banner image]

The URL of the banner is http://engine.adzerk.net/redirect/0/7599/2444/8277/c8dc609ffa9846f49411e88b60a7c7d5/45/1178/12016/634612250633366950?keywords=c%23%2cwinforms%2clistview%2cownerdrawn%2cx-user-registered%2cx-200plus-rep, which redirects to https://www.surveymonkey.com/s/GQGJWSS.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry about that Dan.  We had turned off the survey, but the banner was still up on the site.  The survey is now closed.  I will be posting a blog post releasing the survey results in the next week or so.

Comment: I'm curious - despite visiting multiple times a day every single day, I never saw this - was it on SO or another site? Was it targetted to users in any way?

Comment: @slugster: that's curious indeed, I saw it often enough on SO to wonder how much money they were forgoing from actual advertising in order to get some survey results.

Comment: @sarnold I assumed they mixed it in with the cross stack exchange banners.